# SharePoint 2007 Sample Data to test migration third party migration tools

Tags: content-migration, third-party-software

I'm looking to test a couple of third party migration tools for a migration from 2007 to 2013.  I have a plain 2007 and 2013 farm.  I'm wondering if there is a place to download some 2007 sites that contains sample data and also includes some custom features / workflow, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think it is better idea to test the tool with sample data. Rather, i would use the original data to get the better results. may be things work with general data but may be fail with your environment.I think:

- i would copy the data( few site collection) from you production farm to lower(test or dev) farm. If you dont have, you can crate one server farm.
- now test this data with yours migration tool.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  It's a long story, but I don't have access to the production data yet.  I wanted to do a "dry run" of the migration tools in preparation for when I have access to the actual data.  Was just looking for a quicker way to set up test data.

Comment: i dont think, you will get the sample data, because it is very hard to use...SharePoint is sensitive with Version number and other pieces...But getting 2007 data now is hard....may be you can think about Fab 40 templates...if you get thiose